# como hago para sacar una lista de aquí?

Tags: python, lista, binance

tengo una definición, que print valores ¿como hago para sacar fuera de la definición una lista que usar?
tengo que escribir mas ... pero básicamente es eso, necesito sacar la lista fuera del def y no se como hacer eso ... necesito usar los valores de la lista fuera ... pero no se llamar a a esos valores de la lista
este es el código completo:

```
from http import client
from operator import index
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager
import pandas as pd
import config003
from binance.client import Client


    client = Client(config003.API_KEY, config003.API_SECRET, tld='com')
    symbolo='BTCUSDT'
    btc_price = {'error':False}
    
    
    def trade_history(msg):
        ''' define how to process incoming WebSocket messages '''
        if msg['e'] != 'error':
            print(msg)
            print(msg['c'])
            print(msg['E'])
            print(msg['o'])
            print(msg['h'])
            print(msg['l'])
            print(msg['v'])
            btc_price['last'] = msg['c']
            btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
            btc_price['last'] = msg['a']
            btc_price['error'] = False
            indexes[0]=msg['E']
            indexes[1]=msg['o']
            indexes[2]=msg['h']
            indexes[3]=msg['l']
            indexes[4]=msg['v']
            print(indexes)
            return indexes
        else:
            btc_price['error'] = True
    
    
    
    #tiempo = msg['E']
    
    
    
    # init and start the WebSocket
    bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
    bsm.start()
    
    # subscribe to a stream
    bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback=trade_history, symbol=symbolo)
```

he intentado llamar a la lista indexes ... pero no ocurre algo ... también me lanza un error si hago lo siguiente:

```
lista=trade_history(msg)
print(lista)
```

por favor, que tengo que hacer para poder usar los valores de la lista indexes, el error que lanza es el siguiente: Traceback (most recent call last):
lista=trade_history(msg)
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined

Comment: ¿Qué lista? ya estás retornando `datas` que es la lista `indexes`

Comment: si ... quiero usar la lista index ... si he escrito de más

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien que lista quieres usar fuera de la `def trade_history()` Si quieres sacar fuera de la función algo usa el return ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo():
   lista = []
   return lista
```

Como ya has puesto algo en el `return` pon:

```
return valor1, valor2
```

Luego al usar la funcion en otro lado:

```
resultado = funcion()
```

Espero que sirva!

Comment: pero que función()? ¿una nueva función? yo lo que quiero es la lista, los últimos valores de esa lista (que va recorriendo y cogiendo los últimos valores....

Comment: has puesto return datas vale, pues cuando vayas a querer usar el datas en otro lado simplemente tienes que al llamar a la funcion meter el resultado que te da la funcion en una variable es decir:  lista = trade_history(msg) y ya esta en lista la lista de la funcion

Comment: Lo de mi respuesta es solo un ejemplo, no tienes que crear nuevas funciones simplemente tienes que ''recoger'' el resultado del return en alguna variable, y asi puedes usar esa variable en donde quieras usarla, dicha variable va a contener la lista que has llenado en tu trade_history()

Comment: no entiendo tu ejemplo. ¿podrías ser mas explícito y escribir la solución con mis valores? has escrito 5 incógnitas y solo dos parámetros ... eso es una ecuación irresoluble

Comment: entiendo lo que dices ... si llamo a la función me debería devolver lo que hay en return ... pero escribo lo siguiente y no printea una m***   trade_history = lista

print(lista) además ... tal y como lo he escrito con al eso de arriba, solo me imprime el primer lista de inicialización ... no me imprime el lista que llama a la función ... no se como salir del callback ¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: Si no escribe nada es que la lista esta vacía o algo estas haciendo regular, he visto el nuevo código pero no puedo ejecutarlo ya que esta incompleto. para meter cosas a una lista usa la función *append()* propia de python.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el método que has escrito funciona bien (puedes poner algunos prints para debuggear), es simplemente llamar a esa función en el main (o donde sea que la llames). La respuesta de @SMK creo que lo explica bien, pero voy a ponerlo tod junto.

Por partes, la función se llama aquí:

```
bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback=trade_history, symbol=symbolo)
```

Pero está definida con un parámetro, así que imagino que tendrás que obtener el mensaje de alguna manera, y pasárselo a la función `trade_history(mensaje)`

Veo un poco de lío en el orden de estructura: hay varias lineas que se ejecutan, luego tienes la definición de una función (por nomenclatura en Python, las funciones se definen arriba y luego en un `main` iría la ejecución del código (incluyendo llamando a esas funciones), y luego más código.

Si el orden, ignorando la función, es el que tienes, quedaría algo como:

```
from http import client
from operator import index
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager
import pandas as pd
import config003
from binance.client import Client

def trade_history(msg):
''' define how to process incoming WebSocket messages '''
    if msg['e'] != 'error':
        print(msg)
        print(msg['c'])
        print(msg['E'])
        print(msg['o'])
        print(msg['h'])
        print(msg['l'])
        print(msg['v'])
        btc_price['last'] = msg['c']
        btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
        btc_price['last'] = msg['a']
        btc_price['error'] = False
        indexes[0]=msg['E']
        indexes[1]=msg['o']
        indexes[2]=msg['h']
        indexes[3]=msg['l']
        indexes[4]=msg['v']
        print(indexes)
        return indexes
    else:
        btc_price['error'] = True
        # Aqui quieres devolver algo? O que actualice esto pero no devuelva nada? 
    
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    client = Client(config003.API_KEY, config003.API_SECRET, tld='com')
    symbolo='BTCUSDT'
    btc_price = {'error':False}
    #tiempo = msg['E']
    
    
    
    # init and start the WebSocket
    bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
    bsm.start()
    
    # subscribe to a stream 
    # Aquí deberías llamar a trade_history con el debido mensaje
    bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback=trade_history, symbol=symbolo)
    
    # La forma sencilla de hacerla
    
#     mensaje = 'obtener_msj_de_alguna_manera'
#     lista_final = trade_history(mensaje)
#     print(lista_final)
```

Comment: gracias ... no se como llamar a msg ... a ver si alguien sabe como

Comment: No entiendo... Es decir, si tu has escrito este código, y has puesto definido una función que toma un parámetro, no entiendo lo de *no sé como llamar a msg*.si lo has puesto como parámetro (que debes obtener en algún punto antes de llamar a  `trade_history` )@user245689